# query for total column in every rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't find right query solution to add total column for every row

table

```
+-----+---------+
|id   |amount   |
+-----+---------+
|1    |1000     |
+-----+---------+
|2    |2050     |
+-----+---------+
|3    |2666     |
+-----+---------+
```

needed result

```
+-----+---------+---------+
|id   |amount   |total    |
+-----+---------+---------+
|1    |1000     |1000     |
+-----+---------+---------+
|2    |2050     |3050     |
+-----+---------+---------+
|3    |2666     |5716     |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

ps: amount could be +/-

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
  ,(@runningtotal:= @runningtotal + t.amount) as RunningTotal
FROM
  TableName t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runningtotal:= 0) var
```

Yep with a variable you can do it without a sub query.  Here is a SQL fiddle of the example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/956a2c/2

Comment: thanks Matt, do you think it's good in performance with about hundreds rows?

Comment: I don't actually use mysql much so I am not fully positive but it should be a similar performance to that of a join would be my guess.  hundreds of rows is pretty small in the database world so I don't think you will notice any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a running sum. One way to do it in MySQL is with a correlated sub-query.

```
select id,amount,
amount+coalesce((select sum(amount) from tablename where id<t.id), 0) total
from tablename t
```

[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66896f/4)

Comment: i changed the query. try it with the latest one

Comment: its working now, is there another way without subquery?

Comment: see Matt's answer..using a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.amount,
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM your_table
        WHERE id <= aa.id
    ) AS total
FROM your_table AS aa
```

Comment: its return: `+-----+---------+---------+
|id   |amount   |total    |
+-----+---------+---------+
|1    |1000     |NULL    |
+-----+---------+---------+
|2    |2050     |1000     |
+-----+---------+---------+
|3    |2666     |3050     |
+-----+---------+---------+`

Comment: I just checked it and for me returns the correct results. Check again, now it uses id <= aa.id. But I think Matt's answer is better.